# Positive numbers only validation in a do..while + switch/case statement

Tags: java, validation, integer

I am trying to create validation in a switch statement that will allow only positive integers but when I try entering a negative integer, it does output the error message but does not repeat the loop and just carries on.

This is what I have come up with. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
public void InsertMoney()
{
    String soption;
    productName = " Nothing";

    // Vending machine welcome dialog                   
    soption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        "============================================"
        + "\nWelcome to the College Vending Machine!" 
        + "\n============================================"
        + "\n\nOptions: i for insert money, s for select item, q for quit."
        + "\n\n============================================");

    switch (soption) 
    {
    case "q":       // user chooses q to quit
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a Nice Day!");
        System.exit(0);     // terminate application
        break;
    case "i":       // if user chooses i: insert money;
        do
        {
            spaymentSum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "=============================" 
                + "\nPlease enter some money (in pence)" 
                + "\n=============================");   // Inserting money
            paymentSum = Integer.parseInt(spaymentSum); // Parsing for calculations
            if (paymentSum <= 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Must be a positive input! Try again.");
            }
        } while (paymentSum > 0);
        break;
    case "s":       // if user chooses s: select item
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `paymentSum = 0;` .... `while (paymentSum > 0);` see the problem?

Comment: Your `while` loop is devoid of functionality.

Comment: yes sorry, actually that was not originally in the code but I put it in to test and then forgot to delete it. I have now deleted that..thanks for pointing it out ;)

Comment: yes I would like it to repeat if it is < 0 and = 0 as you can not insert 0 in a vending machine either

Comment: Just use the same condition in your `do ... while` loop as you do in your `if`. As it is, you're looping as long as you have a positive `paymentSum`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting a do/while in a `switch` statement, so long as the entire do/while is contained within a single `case`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK based on AntonH's suggestion I added `while (paymentSum <=0)` instead of what I had originally written at the end `while (paymentSum > 0)` and it worked.

Thanks AntonH!

The new working code is:

```
public void InsertMoney()
{
    String soption;
    productName = " Nothing";

    // Vending machine welcome dialog                   
    soption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        "============================================"
        + "\nWelcome to the College Vending Machine!" 
        + "\n============================================"
        + "\n\nOptions: i for insert money, s for select item, q for quit."
        + "\n\n============================================");

    switch (soption) 
    {
    case "q":       // user chooses q to quit
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a Nice Day!");
        System.exit(0);     // terminate application
        break;
    case "i":       // if user chooses i: insert money;
        do
        {
            spaymentSum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "=============================" 
                + "\nPlease enter some money (in pence)" 
                + "\n=============================");   // Inserting money
            paymentSum = Integer.parseInt(spaymentSum); // Parsing for calculations
            if (paymentSum <= 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Must be a positive input! Try again.");
            }
        } while (paymentSum <= 0); // ADDED CHANGES HERE
        break;
    case "s":       // if user chooses s: select item
        break;
    }
}
```